# Delphi: Components and Controls do not work with Frame

Tags: delphi, controls, components, frame

I open a demo (ICS - SingleD). There are regular controls (edits, labels, panels, buttons, memos) and a component to download files from the Internet.

I want to move them all into a frame.

I create a Frame and:

1) Cut all controls except the component from a main form and paste them into a Frame. Then I change a code for the new frame's controls (e.g. just to cut "Form1" from "Form1.URLEdit.Text" - it will be used in the frame, or to add "Frame11": Frame11.ProgressBar, so it will work from a main form).

Result: the component does not show necessary information in a memo, in a progress bar etc. Nothing happens on the component's events (even if to write "deletefile('1.txt')). Events of visual controlsdo not work (e.g. OnEdit1Change).

2) Cut all controls and the component, paste them into a Frame (all code is changed to  work in the Frame).

Result: one button work, another - no and etc. Even if to write MainForm.Caption:='xxx' - on a button's click then nothing will happen. If to create a new button and to write the same code - all will work.

E.G. TFrame1.btnStopClick does not work here:

```
MAIN FORM
unit main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, clDownLoader, clWinInet, clDC, clDCUtils, clMultiDC, clSingleDC,
  clProgressBar, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, Unit1;

type
  TDownLoaderTest = class(TForm)
    Frame11: TFrame1;
//    procedure btnDownLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Frame11Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 {   procedure btnGetInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtFileChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtUserChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtPasswordChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtURLChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtDirectoryChange(Sender: TObject);}

//    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
//    procedure edtThreadCountChange(Sender: TObject);
//    procedure edtBufferSizeChange(Sender: TObject);
private
 public

  end;

var
  DownLoaderTest: TDownLoaderTest;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}



procedure TDownLoaderTest.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DownLoaderTest.Caption:='1111';
deletefile('aaa');
end;

procedure TDownLoaderTest.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
 // CanClose := not Frame11.clDownLoader1.IsBusy;
end;


procedure TDownLoaderTest.Frame11Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame11.Button1Click(Sender);
end;

end.

FRAME
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, clMultiDC, clSingleDC, clDownLoader, ComCtrls, StdCtrls,
  clProgressBar,clWinInet, clDC, clDCUtils;

type
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
    btnDownLoad: TButton;
    btnGetInfo: TButton;
    btnStop: TButton;
    clProgressBar1: TclProgressBar;
    edtBufferSize: TEdit;
    edtDirectory: TEdit;
    edtFile: TEdit;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    edtStatistic: TEdit;
    edtThreadCount: TEdit;
    edtURL: TEdit;
    edtUser: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label10: TLabel;
    Label11: TLabel;
    Label12: TLabel;
    Label13: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label7: TLabel;
    Label8: TLabel;
    Label9: TLabel;
    memErrors: TMemo;
    memInfo: TMemo;
    memPreview: TMemo;
    updBufferSize: TUpDown;
    updThreadCount: TUpDown;
    clDownLoader1: TclDownLoader;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure btnDownLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnGetInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtFileChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtUserChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtPasswordChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtURLChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtDirectoryChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtThreadCountChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtBufferSizeChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clDownLoader1DataItemProceed(Sender: TObject;
      ResourceInfo: TclResourceInfo; AStateItem: TclResourceStateItem;
      CurrentData: PAnsiChar; CurrentDataSize: Integer);
    procedure clDownLoader1UrlParsing(Sender: TObject;
      var URLComponents: URL_COMPONENTS);
    procedure clDownLoader1StatusChanged(Sender: TObject;
      Status: TclProcessStatus);
    procedure clDownLoader1Changed(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clDownLoader1GetResourceInfo(Sender: TObject;
      ResourceInfo: TclResourceInfo);
    procedure clDownLoader1DataTextProceed(Sender: TObject; Text: TStrings);
    procedure clDownLoader1Error(Sender: TObject; const Error: string;
      ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation
   uses main;
  var FIsLoading: Boolean;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrame1.btnDownLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
memInfo.Lines.Clear();
memErrors.Lines.Clear();
clDownLoader1.Start(True);
end;

procedure TFrame1.btnGetInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
memInfo.Lines.Clear();
memErrors.Lines.Clear();
clDownLoader1.GetResourceInfo(True);
end;


////////  btnStopClick Does NOT work!!!!
procedure TFrame1.btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
DownLoaderTest.Caption:='sss';
clDownLoader1.Stop();
end;
////////  btnStopClick WORKS!!!!!!!!
procedure TFrame1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DownLoaderTest.Caption:='1111';
clDownLoader1.Stop();
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1Changed(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsLoading then Exit;
  FIsLoading := True;
  try
    edtURL.Text := clDownLoader1.URL;
    edtUser.Text := clDownLoader1.UserName;
    edtPassword.Text := clDownLoader1.Password;
    edtFile.Text := clDownLoader1.LocalFile;
  edtDirectory.Text := clDownLoader1.LocalFolder;
   updThreadCount.Position := clDownLoader1.ThreadCount;
    updBufferSize.Position := clDownLoader1.BatchSize;
  finally
    FIsLoading := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1DataItemProceed(Sender: TObject;
  ResourceInfo: TclResourceInfo; AStateItem: TclResourceStateItem;
  CurrentData: PAnsiChar; CurrentDataSize: Integer);
var
  State: TclResourceStateList;
begin
deletefile('d:\1.rar');
  State := AStateItem.ResourceState;
edtStatistic.Text := Format('%.2n of %.2n Kb proceed, speed %.2n Kb/sec, elapsed %.2n min, remains %.2n min',
    [State.BytesProceed / 1024, State.ResourceSize / 1024, State.Speed / 1024,
    State.ElapsedTime / 60, State.RemainingTime / 60]);
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1DataTextProceed(Sender: TObject; Text: TStrings);
begin
 memPreview.Lines.Assign(Text);
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1Error(Sender: TObject; const Error: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
 memErrors.Lines.Text := (Sender as TclDownLoader).Errors.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1GetResourceInfo(Sender: TObject;
  ResourceInfo: TclResourceInfo);
var
  s: String;
begin
  if (ResourceInfo <> nil) then
  begin
    s := 'Resource ' + ResourceInfo.Name + '; Size ' + IntToStr(ResourceInfo.Size)
      + '; Date ' + DateTimeToStr(ResourceInfo.Date)
      + '; Type ' + ResourceInfo.ContentType;
    if ResourceInfo.Compressed then
    begin
      s := s + '; Compressed';
    end;
  end else
  begin
    s := 'There are no any info available.';
  end;
memInfo.Lines.Add(s);
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1StatusChanged(Sender: TObject;
  Status: TclProcessStatus);
var
  s: String;
begin
  case Status of
    psSuccess: MessageBox(0, 'Process completed successfully', 'Message', 0);
    psFailed:
      begin
        s := (Sender as TclDownLoader).Errors.Text;
        MessageBox(0, PChar(s), 'Error', 0);
      end;
    psTerminated: MessageBox(0, 'Process stopped', 'Message', 0);
    psErrors: MessageBox(0, 'Process completed with some warnings', 'Message', 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TFrame1.clDownLoader1UrlParsing(Sender: TObject;
  var URLComponents: URL_COMPONENTS);
begin
  with URLComponents do
  begin
    memInfo.Lines.Add('Scheme: ' + lpszScheme);
    memInfo.Lines.Add('Host: ' + lpszHostName);
   memInfo.Lines.Add('User: ' + lpszUserName);
    memInfo.Lines.Add('Path: ' + lpszUrlPath);
    memInfo.Lines.Add('Extra: ' + lpszExtraInfo);
  end;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtBufferSizeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsLoading then Exit;
 clDownLoader1.BatchSize := updBufferSize.Position;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtDirectoryChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if FIsLoading then Exit;
 clDownLoader1.LocalFolder := edtDirectory.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtFileChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsLoading then Exit;
clDownLoader1.LocalFile := edtFile.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtPasswordChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsLoading then Exit;
 clDownLoader1.Password := edtPassword.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtThreadCountChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if FIsLoading then Exit;
clDownLoader1.ThreadCount := updThreadCount.Position;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtURLChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if FIsLoading then Exit;
clDownLoader1.URL := edtURL.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame1.edtUserChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsLoading then Exit;
clDownLoader1.UserName := edtUser.Text;
end;

end.
```

What wrong I do with frames? It is not a problem of components or controls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a result of cut & paste, the button and it's click handler is not associated in the .dfm of the frame.

Select 'btnStop' of the frame in the design editor, click on the 'Events' tab of the OI, select 'OnClick' and click the down arrow at the right side, find and select 'btnStopClick' from the list.

Comment: All is ok with an association. I have checked.

Comment: It was my fault. I have built manually what I had needed. Now all is ok. Thanks!

Comment: When you do this you can view the .dfm as text and copy it that way.t and copy it that way.